# How do you say "hasn't been much activity" using "to go on"?

Tags: word-usage

"In the ensuing few months there hasn’t been much to go on in terms of new hints of what it might look like."

I read this sentence in an online article and interpreted it as "there hasn't been much activity regarding xyz" but shouldn't it have been written as "hasn't been much gone on" instead? Although I admit, that sounds weird - what is the correct grammar of "to go on" ?

Comment: Your interpretation isn’t right. “There hasn’t been much to go on” means that there hasn’t been much (in terms of new hints) to base guesses and conclusions on. To _go on X_ (stress on _go_, not on _on_) means to use _X_ as a basis for something further; for example, if someone sets you a difficult task and you have only very little material to work with as your basis, you can say, “I’ll do my best, but I don’t have much to go on, so it will be difficult”.

Comment: I think you're mixing this up with *there hasn't been much going on*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you read the sentence as if it said:

> "In the ensuing few months there *hasn't been much going on* in terms of new hints of what it might look like."

However, that is not what the sentence actually says.

*There hasn't been much to go on* is idiomatic and means as much as:

> There have not been many hints about what it might look like.

If someone says "I don't have much to go on", it means "I do not have a lot I can use to do something".

> I should make the design, but I don't have much to go on.
>   I was asked to make a forecast for the next quarter, but I don't have much to go on.

The first sentence says I am probably waiting for input before I can make the design. The second one means that I am probably missing the relevant statistics that I need to make a forecast.